# Two passports with "different" names

Tags: passports, tickets, international-travel, dual-nationality

I have 2 passports with same name but different first name and surname, I need to use both in my next travel.

```
Passport 1 - Name: João Manuel 
             Surname: da Silva Couto 
Passport 2 - Name: João Manuel da Silva 
             Surname: Couto.
```

Will I have problems on check-in or at immigration?

Comment: You could have problems depending on which country you are going to particularly if it is to a third country which is not one of your nationalities. However because the name string is the same but only split differently in the two passports, you are more likely to get a pass. Which country are you going to, is it with a visa etc. More complete information would be helpful.

Comment: I'm travelling between contries that I have citizenship, no need of visa, with a layover in a third country but I won't get out of the security zone.

Comment: No, it's not duplicated, differente questions.

Comment: @Mandrek It's not clear to me what your question is, then. Is it that the name on your plane ticket matches one of your passports but not the other? I'm sure we have questions about that, too. It's hard to imagine that there'll be a problem: it's not like they're two completely different names; it's obviously the same name that's just been broken up differently.

Answer (score 3):

Without know the specifics, it is impossible to give you an absolute answer. Since you have tagged this question as *dual-nationality*, this answer assumes that you have one passport for each nationality and they should be both valid (an invalid passport is a different issue).

First of all, middle and second names are *usually* not a problem. Sometimes they get abbreviated or omitted even. Your first name matches in both cases and so does your second last name, so it would be fair to say that there would be little doubt these are not for the same person, particularly since your date-of-birth and place-of-birth (if specified) also match.

Most importantly, immigration *rarely* asks to see more than one passport at a given point. You may be even able to travel with just one but if both are in fact needed for a particular trip, then you show one to immigration at your home country (when exiting on your way out and entering on your way back) and the other at your destination country (on your way and out). You also show the passport for your home country at check-in but that is to validate that you can be let in at the destination. A few countries have no exit immigration step, so nothing to show there.

Comment: I have to buy the plane ticket using one of the passports (I will use the passport from the country that I'm travelling to) so I think there won't be a porblem checking-in but to come back I have to show the passport from the country that I didn't use to buy the ticket (with a little difference in the names).

Comment: Buying a ticket does not normally require a passport - *perhaps in your country* - but usually not as you can buy tickets for other people. A passport is required at check-in which happens twice for a two-way flight. Often when checking in for the return leg, you have the option to use the previous info but it is possible to return on a different passport, even if you only had one nationality (lost passport  for example).  When you come back, check-in looks at your passport to see if you can take the flight back which is to use the other passport. Many people I traveled with must do that.

Comment: You can usually use both passports at check-in, that is, if your countries allow double nationality.

Comment: They may ask to see the passport at check-in? In the Netherlands we've had to get a new ticket printed because it said 'Willem' while the name on the passport is 'Wilhelmus'. This was last month! (Amsterdam-Split, Easyjet)